# Models in the Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, model

What are some of the ways you have implemented models in the Zend Framework?

I have seen the basic `class User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` and then putting calls to that in your controllers:

`$foo = new User;`

`$foo->fetchAll()`

but what about more sophisticated uses? The Quickstart section of the documentation offers such an example but I still feel like I'm not getting a "best use" example for models in Zend Framework. Any interesting implementations out there?

---

**EDIT:** I should clarify (in response to CMS's comment)... I know about doing more complicated selects. I was interested in overall approaches to the Model concept and concrete examples of how others have implemented them (basically, the stuff the manual leaves out and the stuff that basic how-to's gloss over)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I personally subclass both `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` and `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract`. The main difference between my code and yours is that explicitly treat the subclass of `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` as a "table" and `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` as "row".  Very rarely do I see direct calls to select objects, SQL, or the built in ZF database methods in my controllers.  I try to hide the logic of requesting specific records to calls for behind `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` like so:

```
class Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'users';

    protected $_rowClass = 'User'; // <== THIS IS REALLY HELPFUL

    public function getById($id) {
        // RETURNS ONE INSTANCE OF 'User'
    }

    public function getActiveUsers() {
        // RETURNS MULTIPLE 'User' OBJECTS            
    }

}

class User extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {

    public function setPassword() {
        // SET THE PASSWORD FOR A SINGLE ROW
    }

}

/* CONTROLLER */
public function setPasswordAction() {

    /* GET YOUR PARAMS */

    $users = new Users();

    $user = $users->getById($id);

    $user->setPassword($password);

    $user->save();
}
```

There are numerous ways to approach this. Don't think this is the only one, but I try to follow the intent of the ZF's design.  (Here are more of my [thoughts and links on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773/zend-php-framework#58837).)  This approach does get a little class heavy, but I feel it keeps the controllers focused on handling input and coordinating with the view; leaving the model to do the application specific work.

Comment: Should "protected $_rowClass = 'Users';" have been "protected $_rowClass = 'User';"?

Comment: $users->getById($id) can be replaced with built in find method $users->find($id)->current();

Answer (score 62):

I worked for Zend and did quite a bit of work on the Zend_Db_Table component.

Zend Framework doesn't give a lot of guidance on the concept of a "Model" with respect to the Domain Model pattern.  There's no base class for a Model because the Model encapsulates some part of business logic specific to your application.  I wrote a [blog](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2008/05/activerecord-does-not-suck.html) about this subject in more detail.

Persistence to a database should be an internal implementation detail of a Model.  The Model typically *uses* one or more Table.  It's a common but improper object-oriented design to consider a Model as an extension of a Table.  In other words, we should say Model HAS-A Table -- not Model IS-A Table.

This is an example of IS-A:

```
class MyModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
}
```

This is an example of HAS-A:

```
class MyModel // extends nothing
{
    protected $some_table;
}
```

In a real domain model, you would *use* $some_table in the methods of MyModel.

You can also read Martin Fowler's take on the [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) design pattern, and his description of the [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) antipattern, which is how many developers unfortunately approach OO programming.

Comment: "... did quite a bit of work on the Zend_Db_Table..." 
I know you did, Bill. I'm something of a fan of your php work, to be honest.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't start the project, I only took over when the original guys moved on.  Paul M. Jones (http://paul-m-jones.com/) deserves the credit as architect of the Zend_Db components.

Comment: To paraphrase: Fat Model & skinny controller is good. Skinny model & fat controller is bad.

Comment: @Benedict: Right, but it's worth describing exactly what we mean by those terms, and why one is good and the other is bad.

Comment: Your blog is excellent Bill, but why not putting that in the ZF documentation !? When I did the quickstart for the 1st time, I didn't understood the "model/mapper/Zend_Db_Table" thing.

Comment: Thanks @Matthieu, I wrote the blog after I left the ZF project.  I've developed that blog into a chapter of my new book, "SQL Antipatterns" http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns

Comment: I'm quite new to Zend. Can you maybe give a little example of "Model has a table" and "Model is a table"? Do you mean i can use Zend_Db_Table within my model but i shouldn't extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract?

Comment: @xotix: I've added a brief example of what I mean.

Comment: Okay. If i have for example: http://pastebin.com/Ugjv6saN i would create a model which looks something like: http://pastebin.com/6GY801HD (just as a example of the principle) also if have e.g. controller "user" and action "new", i could just use Zend_Db_Table_Row. The idea, creating a model which extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract is close. So i can use its methods directly on my model's object in the action. Since i should create a model which just HAS a table_row, i'd have to create my own save function which calls the function of my Zend_Db_Table_Row Object. eg: http://pastebin.com/6cHbvtCT

Comment: Yes, I think you're close to it.  Just think of it this way:  a Domain Model represents some part of your application domain, so its methods should correspond to tasks your application performs.  Internally the Domain Model reads and writes data from a database, but this should be hidden.  Callers (like the controller) should not have to invoke CRUD functions.  This helps you decouple Models from Controllers, helps you avoid duplicating code in several Controllers, helps you write mocks for unit testing your Models, etc.

Comment: After reading this and toor's answer, let me ask, but what if you know your model has a lot to do with a (or "is a") database table? Why not extend from a class that adds DB functionality? toor said ">In that case<, model might not extend anything". I think it depends on the situation? I go for the Fat Model approach, I not only use Models for DB interactivity, everything regarding it goes there, including files logic (eg. images) if the case, but if I know the model "is a" table, well... why not?

Comment: @renocor, say you have two totally separate application subsystems that happen to use the same table.  Do you code the functionality of both subsystems in the table class?  What if one of those subsystems also uses other tables?  Now you have a table that has code referencing other tables, but only sometimes.  It's a sure route to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 7):

Don't ever use Zend_Db_Table as your model. It just gets you into trouble. Either you write your own model classes which use Zend_Db_Table to talk to your database or you can read my blog post [here](http://www.zacharysnow.com/2008/06/20/zend_db_table-as-a-model/) for a hack that allows you to somewhat combine the "Model" class and Zend_Db_Table.

The main thing to not is that when you use Zend_Db_Table directly in your controllers you end up doing the same things in multiple places. If you have to make a change to some of that logic, you have to make a change in multiple places. Not good. My first professional project was done like this because I was the one in the company who had to learn how to use ZF and it's a total mess now.

I also tend to write helper functions into my classes for sophisticated fetches. Somthing like $table->doNameFetchAll() or $table->doOrderFetchAll().

Comment: Your link is broken, do you have another copy of said resource?

Comment: @x-istence It seems that blog moved from .com to .net domain. Here is the link: http://zacharysnow.net/2008/06/20/zend_db_table-as-a-model/

Comment: Sorry, just saw this comment thread for the first time. I wrote that article long ago. If you writing a new application going forward I would take more of the approach presented in the Zend Framework quickstart: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

Answer (score 7):

I've been doing some research on Models for ZF and came across an interesting series of articles by Matthew Weier O'Phinney which are well worth checking out:

- [Using Zend_Form in your Models](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models.html)
- [Applying ACLs to Models](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/201-Applying-ACLs-to-Models.html)
- [Model Infrastructure](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/202-Model-Infrastructure.html)

It's not "production code" and a lot is left to the imagination, but it's a good read and has helped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

A model has **nothing to do with the database**. What if I am fetching data from an RSS feed or a SOAP service or reading files from the FS?

I put all these kinds of things in models. In that case, my model class might **not extend anything**. I'm about to write a model that uses methods of other models.

Comment: Absolutely agree! Although this is dated question, many people still come and look here, so I will postmy solution. I have written article how I have implemented Model and ORM in zend framework. Hope it helps to many people. it's on : http://havl.net/devnotes/2010/10/zendframework-model-orm/

Answer (score 3):

Skip ZF for the models part, there are much better solutions. The "M" in ZF's "MVC" is pretty much absent. Reading their docs they don't really mention models at all -- which is a good thing, it means you can use just about anything you want without writing lots of adapter code.

Take a look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) for models instead. It is quickly becoming the de-facto ORM for PHP.

Comment: Doctrine would be awesome but I cannot be certain of having access to versions of PHP current enough to satisfy doctrine's requirements.

Comment: Doctrine says it requires PHP 5.2.3, while ZF requires PHP 5.1.4 but also strongly recommends 5.2.3 for its security and performance benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do more complicated queries, check the [Advanced usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.advanced.usage) section in the [`Zend_Db_Table`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) manual page.

```
$select = $table->select();
$select->from($table,
              array('COUNT(reported_by) as `count`', 'reported_by'))
       ->where('bug_status = ?', 'NEW')
       ->group('reported_by');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract class and add some useful methods to it. for example you can add a changePassword() method to your user class and manipulate it's data. or you can change the default __toString() method of your class, so you'll have a customized __toString() method that, let's say returns the whole contact information of the user (name, address, phone number) in a well formatted string. in your constructor you could populate your data into properties of your object. then use them like:

```
public function __toString() {
   $data = $this->_name . ', ' . $this->_adderss . ', call: ' . $this->_phone;
   return $data;
}
```

your model extends the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract just to ease the process of accessing its data, but the functionality you could have on that data is all up on your creativity and need.
I recommend you the book "php|architect's guide to programming with zend framework" by Cal Evans. the book is very informative and easy to read. chapters 4 and 6 are going to be useful for this matter.

Answer (score 1):

A database entity is not the only kind of model component. As such, it doesn't really make sense to speak of models (in plural) - Your application has *one* model, which contains a multitude of components. Some of these components could be table gateways (And thus extend from `Zend_Db`), while others would not.

I recommend that you get hold of the book [Domain Driven Design](http://books.google.com/books?id=7dlaMs0SECsC&dq=Domain+Driven+Design&pg=PP1&ots=ulAU40W7s1&source=bn&sig=RIl_hphC_4_esto9wSYmm7FJ81s&hl=da&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=4&ct=result#PPR9,M1) by Eric Evans, which does an excellent job of explaining how to construct an object model.

Answer (score 1):

I use Propel 1.3 instead of Zend_Db_Table.
It's tricky to setup, but awesome.
It can examine your database and auto-generate all your models.
It actually generates 2 levels and 2 types of model.

Examples for 'user' table:

Level 1: BaseModel & BasePeer: these get overwritten every time you regenerate your ORM. i.e. BaseUser.php & BaseUserPeer.php

Level 2: StubModel & StubPeer: these don't get overwritten. They're the ones you customize. i.e. User.php & UserPeer.php

Type 1: Model - for basic CRUD operations, not queries i.e. User.php
Type 2: Peer -- for queries. These are static objects. i.e. UserPeer.php

So to create a user:

```
$derek = new User();
$derek->setFirstName('Derek');
$derek->save();
```

To find all dereks:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(UserPeer::FIRST_NAME, 'Derek');
$dereks = UserPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://zfsite.andreinikolov.com/2008/08/zend_db_table-time-overhead-about-25-percents/

Bit of a catch 22, Zend_Table is nice in principle, but generates some performance overheads (without caching)...