# zend models architecture

Tags: zend-framework, architecture, model

Let's say I have two tables in a database: projects and users. I create two models, that extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract: `Model_DbTable_Users` and `Model_DbTable_Projects`.

Now, is it a good pattern to create an instance of `Model_DbTable_Projects` inside the `Model_DbTable_Users` class ? In other words: is it OK to put any logic in this model, or should I create another class, that uses `Model_DbTable_Users` and `Model_DbTable_Projects`?

I use to put all the logic in models, that extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, but in large projects it can make code very unclean. So, can you give me any advice on models architecture(links on articles would be great!).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was the project lead for the Zend Framework project through version 1.0.  My contributions were mainly in the Zend_Db component.

I frequently [advise](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2008/05/activerecord-does-not-suck.html) that people should use the [Domain Model](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) pattern and avoid the [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) antipattern.  Remember that **a Table is not a Model.**

Your Model is a class (extending no base class) for code that encapsulates your business logic.  The relationship between a Model and a Table isn't IS-A, it's HAS-A (or HAS-MANY).  The Model treats database persistence as an implementation detail.  The consumer of a Model should have no clue about your database structure (this allows you to change database structure without changing the Model's interface).

I'm basically repeating the answer I gave to [Models in the Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294875/models-in-the-zend-framework/295051#295051).

Here is some more reading:

- http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/202-Model-Infrastructure.html
- http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/373-The-M-in-MVC-Why-Models-are-Misunderstood-and-Unappreciated.html
- http://n4.nabble.com/Another-Model-Design-Thread-td670076.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are there any examples of the Domain Model with Zend framework?