# Creating DbTables, models and mappers for every single table

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, zend-framework, model, class-design

I'm trying to follow Zend Framework's conventions as much as possible.

In my application, is it recommended to write a DbTable, a Mapper, and the Model class for every single table in my DB? Even tables like `user_permission`? (the fields on that one are `user_id, permission_id`, and are both the PK).

If the answer is no, then how would a situation like that be modelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't create a model for each table but for each domain object and add a reference to the other domain. In your case that'd be `User` and `Permission`. You'd still have to create a `DbTable` for each table, but that shouldn't be too hard.
I think [survithedeepend](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors) has done real good in explaining that even if it's a lot to read. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294875/models-in-the-zend-framework) might be helpfull for further readings on data modeling ;)

Comment: I'd say that you probably want a DbTable for each table that will be queried without joins to other tables and not necessarily for every table. Otherwise, +1 for Fge's answer.

Comment: Well, this was really helpful, I feel like such a beginner.. I guess every time you learn something new you realize how much more you don't know...