# how to create and use zend framework model like codeigniter?

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, model, controller

Both frameworks have seperate Model, View, Controller directories. My doubt is how to use model in Zend Framework.

[ CodeIgniter Controller ]

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('users_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        // here i am using model function //
        $this->user_model->login();
    }
}
?>
```

[ Zend Framework Controller ]

```
<?php
class UsersController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // how to load model and use here ???? //
    }
}
?>
```

In CodeIgniter Controller I load model "users+_model" and used in index function. In the same way how to create zend model and use in controller? please help me, I am sorry my english is not good.

Thanks friends,
Rajendra

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294875/models-in-the-zend-framework

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're stuck on the idea of "loading" a model.  CI is a much more rigid system than ZF and almost shields the developer from working with Classes directly.

In ZF you declare classes in `Models` or if you have modules enabled `Default/Models` and work with them directly by instantiating them.

`$dog = new Default_Model_Dog()`

or even something like

`$dog = Default_Model_Dog::createDog()`

If you plan on working with a database a lot, then I **STRONGLY** suggest you learn Doctrine ORM and use that with ZF
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm

It's a fantastic piece of software that makes working a database much more bearable in ZF. It will take a little bit to learn, but it will pay back in time saved later on.